# finding the rows containing any element of a list, in R

Tags: r, matrix, row, match

suppose I have the following matrix:

```
mm <- matrix(c(1,2,3,5,3,6,7,9,3,4,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,4,4,0,2,5,6,2,3,0,1,2,1,1,8,2,7,1,2,3,1,2,0,3),10,2)
```

Now I would like to see which rows present, TWO of ANY of these values:

```
values<-c(2,3,4,9)
```

for instance, I would like to highlight a hypothetical row containing:

2,3

or

9,4

so, both elements of the row need to be in the "values" list.

any idea?

thank you very much in advance!

Tina.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (I wonder if there is simpler!)

```
mm[rowSums(matrix(mm %in% values, nrow(mm)) == 2, ]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    3    2
[3,]    9    4
[4,]    3    4
```